# Charge Conjugation of Dirac equation

Tags: field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, charge-conjugation

In contituation of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/699608/a-problem-with-qed) question

In answers of this question people mentioned charged conjugation and formula below

$\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi=u^2-v^2$

With $u$ for particles and $v$ for antiparticles

If I got everything right

$\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi=\bar{\psi}_+\gamma^\mu\psi_+-\bar{\psi}_-\gamma^\mu\psi_-$

Where $\psi_+$ are particles and $\psi_-$ are antiparticles

$\psi_-=C\bar{\psi}_+$

So

$\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi=\bar{\psi}_+\gamma^\mu\psi_+-\bar{C}\psi_+\gamma^\mu C\bar{\psi}_+$

$\bar{C}=C^{T*}\gamma^0$

Since $C=\gamma^2\gamma^0=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & i\\ 
0 & 0 & -i & 0\\ 
0 & -i & 0 & 0\\ 
-i & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

$\bar{C}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & -i\\ 
0 & 0 & i & 0\\ 
0 & i & 0 & 0\\ 
-i & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=\gamma^2$

So

$\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi=\bar{\psi}_+\gamma^\mu\psi_+-\gamma^2\psi_+\gamma^\mu \gamma^2\gamma^0\bar{\psi}_+$

For electric field $\mu=0$

$\bar{\psi}\gamma^0\psi=\bar{\psi}_+\gamma^0\psi_+-\gamma^2\psi_+\gamma^0 \gamma^2\gamma^0\bar{\psi}_+$

Substituting the Dirac matrices we get

$\bar{\psi}\gamma^0\psi=0$

So no electric potential is created at all.

It seems that I didn't get something the right way. Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third equation has no basis. And you should decide first if you assume that the components of the Dirac spinor are complex numbers or Grassmaniann numbers, or operators with canonical anticommuting relations. Because if they are complex numbers, your first equation is also wrong.

Comment: I assume that they're complex numbers. What is the equation in that case?

Comment: @JavaGamesJAR : Then you don't have antiparticles, you only have positive- and negative-energy states. The charge density has the same sign for positive- and negative-energy states.

Comment: So I have to use Dirac sea for antiparticles?

Comment: The problem is that by QED equation for $A^\mu$ the potential will accelerate or should I just subtract vacuum state from the $\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi$?

Comment: @JavaGamesJAR : I don't know what you're trying to achieve, so I don't know what you should do. If you assume that the components of the Dirac spinor are complex numbers, then the charge density will always be negative (if $e<0$). And, by the way, your second equation is also wrong under this assumption.

Comment: I'm trying to make a computer program modeling QFT in a "box". My first aim is to model a decaying positronium. So I need both particles and antiparticles. By the way, the Dirac Sea didn't work properly

Comment: @JavaGamesJAR : Then you probably need the components of the Dirac spinor to satisfy the canonical anti-commutation relations.

Comment: First of all, what are those relations and which of the equations are right under these circumstances?

Comment: Also, is there any way to make this work with complex numbers?

Comment: @JavaGamesJAR : I am afraid I cannot help with your problem.

Comment: If so, what are the relations between operators? How is the Dirac spinor represented then?

Comment: @JavaGamesJAR : Look at something like https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-82272-8_9.pdf